# Can you help me understand retain counts in cocoa/objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

```
> .h file:
NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;

> .m file:
self.myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

If i'm not wrong i will end up with an NSString instance with retain count of +2. Right?

I'm curious because Apple's example for Location uses "self." for initialization. Why? I checked and it does show retain count to be +2.

Comment: This question is unclear, and the title isn't a question.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Probably because someone else edited it.

Comment: No, it hasn't been edited, and even the title hadn't been edited yet. (Look at time stamps: Edited 24 mins ago; my comment was at 30 mins ago.)

Comment: someone did changed the title.

Comment: i just found out about this comment feature. was i sleeping, "he asked himself while trying to kick himself on the back" :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your first question:

Yes, the retain count would be two.

---

To answer your second question:

The reason for using:

```
self.myString = x;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[self setMyString:x];
```

is so that all of the property handling code is properly executed. This includes KVO notifications, and the code that automatically retains x as it is passed in.

If you were to simply set:

```
myString = x;
```

in the .m file, you would bypass all of that hidden property setting code, and simply set the myString member variable to a pointer to x.

Answer (score 3):

Mustafa: Yes, you're correct. (The property should be declared as `copy`, not `retain`, but that's another matter.)

Answer (score 1):

In your Modification 1, you're setting your instance variable directly to an autoreleased object. This means that at the end of the event loop your `locationManager` will be released and in this case, you'll then have a reference to a now unused block of memory.

Your Modification 2 looks correct to me, as does the sample code you've started from.